# Making a randomized image based quiz using textbox in php / html

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, textbox

I'm trying to make a guess the picture type of quiz, with a randomized picture as the question while having the user type in the answer inside a textbox. a question/ a pic is going to be randomly picked from 3-5 options with each refresh or after correctly guessing the picture randomize the question again....

So far I have only achieved in randomizing the questions but it's not functioning the way that I want it to, since I can't figure out how to correctly link the function that randomizes with the function that checks if the input is correct or not.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <?php
$var = rand (1,3);

if($var == 1){
    print '<img src="idiom1.jpg">';
    }
if ($var == 2){
    print '<img src="idiom2.jpg">';
    }
if ($var ==3){
    print '<img src="idiom3.jpg">';
    }
?>
<body>
<form method="post">
Your answer<input type="text" name ="answer"/><hr/>
<input type ="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
$answer=$_POST['answer'];
if ($var == 1 && $answer== "to the moon and back"){
    print "you are correct";
    }
    else if  {
    print "you are incorrect";
    }
if ($var == 2 && $answer== "the apple of my eye"){
    print "you are correct";
    }
    else {
    print "you are incorrect";
    }
if ($var == 3 && $answer== "barking"){
    print "you are correct";
    }
    else {
    print "you are incorrect";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're recalculating $var every time the page loads,so unsurprisingly it's different when after you submit  the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try save prev var to session or do it only with javascript.
Or you can add hidden input with correct answer to form.

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Your answer
        <input type="text" name ="answer"/><hr/>
        <input type="hidden" name ="correct" value="<?= $var ?>" />
        <input type ="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Then check

```
<?php
    if($_POST['answer'] == $_POST['correct']){/** Congratulation! **/}
```